# VBA - Categorize based on text in a sequentially manner

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to semi-automate this monthly process in order to save some time. So we get these reports (in Excel) on a monthly basis and the list look something like this:

```
  Amount | Category | Text
     30  |  Blank   | BSP
     70  |  Blank   | PSP
   -350  |  Blank   | Accounting of
    100  |  Blank   | Payment
```

So we need to categorize each `Text` with a letter in sequential manner. In this example, we would label both `BSP` and `PSP` as "A", `Accounting of` as "B", and the next text item as "C" and so on.

Example:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in VBA without a predetermined list or dictionary ( Because each report has different text)?

Comment: Hello Henry and welcome to the site!  I've gone ahead and edited your question, feel free to edit it again if you aren't happy with my changes.  You should also be able to upload your image directly to the site, I would have done it but I am unable to access imgur at work.  Could you please explain why `BSP` and `PSP` were both labeled 'A' instead of 'A' and 'B' since they are different?

Comment: why do the categories above not matching the categories below (in the picture)

Comment: I've added your picture for you Henry - as MackM said, no imgur pictures please :) - you can upload directly instead.

Comment: Hi MackM, thank you for the welcoming. The reason as to why we label both BSP and PSP as "A" instead of a different letter is because we consider them as the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one classic option that you could go with and adjust as needed. Right now i'm kind of informally selecting the range - I don't exactly know enough about the format of your document to do it 'automatically'. Depending on the size/amount of sheets you might change it to `Selection.Cells` which will operate your macro on the highlighted cells in the sheet (i would just highlight all of column B that has the information you're adjusting).

```
Sub Henry()

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("C2:C7").Cells    'picking this range statically based on picture

        Select Case LCase$(cel.Value2)
            Case "bsp", "psp"
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "A"

            Case "accounting of"
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "B"

            Case "debit memo"
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "C"

            '... other cases if necessary...

            Case Else    'default case if necessary - can be "error" or "not found", etc
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "..."
        End Select

    Next cel

End Sub
```

Depending on how open ended, you may have to use the `InStr()` function. It returns `True` if a predetermined string is found within another string. I included this one because, in the second table in the image, one row includes more than just `"BSP"` which would throw off my previous solution

```
Sub Henry()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim temp As String

    For Each cel In Range("C2:C7").Cells    'picking this range statically based on picture

        temp = LCase$(cel.Value2)

        Select Case True
            Case InStr(temp, "bsp") > 0 Or InStr(temp, "psp") > 0
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "A"

            Case InStr(temp, "accounting of") > 0
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "B"

            Case InStr(temp, "debit memo") > 0
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "C"

            '... other cases if necessary...

            Case Else    'default case if necessary - can be "error" or "not found", etc
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "..."
        End Select

    Next cel

End Sub
```

> Is it possible to do this in VBA without a predetermined list or dictionary ( Because each report has different text)?

No, you'll have to manually adjust what the options could be for each sheet since they're all different.

Comment: Thank you Marcucciboy2 for the response. As for the differences between my example and the image - I was in bit of a rush as I'm at work atm. I apologize if that caused any confusion.